# Oracle outer joins

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

have two records returned when I run from table a.

select * from a where a.id = '123'

I then created a temp table t6, note: there are no records for a.id 123 returned in this temp table. I did a left join on table a and t6 with a where clause a.id 123, and expect 2 records to be returned with the values from table t6 will be null or blank. But it returned no rows. I would like to know how to fix to get it to work.

```
select a.*, t6.*
from 
(select t5.column1, t5.column2, t1.column3, t1.column9, t2.column9, t3.column9, t4.column9
from            (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('abcd')
                )  t1
                join (select column3, column8, column9 from t7               
                where upper(column8) = upper('efgh')
                ) t2
                on t2.column3 = t1.column3
                and t1.column3 in (select id2 from a where a.id = '123')
                left outer join
                (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('ijkl')
                ) t3
                on t3.column3 = t1.column3    
                left outer join
               (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('mnop')
                ) t4
                on t4.column3 = t1.column3
                join t5  
                on t1.column9 =  t5.column10
) t6
left join
a
on a.id2 = t6.column3
where a.id = '123'
```

Comment: If you give us test data and expected result example I hope someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table A should be on left side and #t6 should be on righr side.

```
from a 
left join #t6 on on a.id2 = t6.column3
```

**Query**

```
select a.*, t6.*
from a
left join
(select t5.column1, t5.column2, t1.column3, t1.column9, t2.column9, t3.column9, t4.column9
from            (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('abcd')
                )  t1
                join (select column3, column8, column9 from t7               
                where upper(column8) = upper('efgh')
                ) t2
                on t2.column3 = t1.column3
                and t1.column3 in (select id2 from a where a.id = '123')
                left outer join
                (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('ijkl')
                ) t3
                on t3.column3 = t1.column3    
                left outer join
               (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('mnop')
                ) t4
                on t4.column3 = t1.column3
                join t5  
                on t1.column9 =  t5.column10
) t6

on a.id2 = t6.column3
where a.id = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `LEFT JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`.

Or change the direction of the `JOIN` chain:

```
SELECT a.*, t6.*
FROM a LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ..... ) ON a.id2 = t6.column3
WHERE a.id = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand main table is a, so you must write table a at first position like this:

```
select a.*, t6.*
from a left join
(select t5.column1, t5.column2, t1.column3, t1.column9, t2.column9, t3.column9, t4.column9
from            (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('abcd')
                )  t1
                join (select column3, column8, column9 from t7               
                where upper(column8) = upper('efgh')
                ) t2
                on t2.column3 = t1.column3
                and t1.column3 in (select id2 from a where a.id = '123')
                left outer join
                (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('ijkl')
                ) t3
                on t3.column3 = t1.column3    
                left outer join
               (select column3, column8, column9 from t7
                where upper(column8) = upper('mnop')
                ) t4
                on t4.column3 = t1.column3
                join t5  
                on t1.column9 =  t5.column10
) t6
on a.id2 = t6.column3
where a.id = '123'
```